# MS Certificate authority issued to wrong entity

Tags: certificate-authority, netscaler

Hi I have created a CA signing request on my netscaler where the common name  is *.mydomain.com

When I sign the CRS in my MS CA its ends up being issued to "Fredrik" instead of *.mydomain.com

This results in that all browsers panics. I am following a video guide from CBT nugget and I do not think I made a mistake in the CRS process on my Netscaler so I think I might have miss configured my CA in the past (I likely followed another CBT nugget video for this). It has worked fine issuing certificates to my vcenter server and a few other servers in the past.

What can I have missed?

// Fredrik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change subject source in the target certificate template. Open Certificate Templates MMC snap-in, select properties of target template. Switch to Subject tab and switch radiobutton to "Supply in request".

Comment: Hi, The certificate template that is used is "user" (from: http://localhost/certsrv/certrqxt.asp) but this seam to be locked so I cant make any changes to is. I tried to duplicate it but I this copy is not available as an option in the drop down menu.

Comment: I missed to actually create the template. Guide to do this: http://www.derekseaman.com/2012/09/create-vmware-windows-ca-certificate.html